# Why would a query that returns 835 records in Access, return an empty recordset in VBA code?

Tags: vba, adodb, recordset

The following code is slightly modified from some boilerplate I use for almost every project I work on (in Access).  All the other versions of this code work perfectly in this db.  The tables are all actually in SQL Server but they are linked in this Access db.

Here's the weird part...When I run the code and get down into the "With rs" and do the ".Open", the next step "Do While Not .EOF" skips to the bottom of the "Do"...I am at .EOF!  But if I get a copy of the ".Source" SQL Statement and paste it into a blank SQL query on the non-code Access main window, I get 835 records from that query.  How could I be getting back an empty recordset when this query should return 835 records?

I've tried changing my .CursorType and .LockType, to no avail.

Anyone have any thoughts about what I could try in troubleshooting this?

```
Public Sub test()
Dim db As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sFromDate As String
Dim sToDate As String
Dim sSubUnit As String

sFromDate = "1/1/2013"
sToDate = "1/31/2013"
sSubUnit = "2???"

' Make a connection to the db
Set db = CurrentProject.Connection

With rs
    .ActiveConnection = db
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .LockType = adLockReadOnly

    .Source = "SELECT SCEVENT.CLIENT_ID, SCATTEND.EMP_ID, SCATTEND.STARTDATE, SCATTEND.SVC_ID " & _
                "FROM SCATTEND LEFT JOIN SCEVENT ON SCATTEND.SCEVENT_ID = SCEVENT.ID " & _
                "WHERE (SCATTEND.STARTDATE Between #" & sFromDate & "# And #" & sToDate & "#) " & _
                    "AND (SCATTEND.SUBUNIT_ID Like '" & sSubUnit & "') " & _
                    "AND ((APPTYP_ID IS NULL) OR (APPTYP_ID IN (1,2))) " & _
                "ORDER BY SCEVENT.CLIENT_ID, SCATTEND.EMP_ID, SCATTEND.STARTDATE, SCATTEND.SVC_ID;"
    .Open
    Do While Not .EOF
        MsgBox "there are records!"
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have something to do with the difference between ADO and DAO

[Difference between ADO and DAO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737099/difference-between-ado-and-dao)

Comment: That was exactly it!  I changed the single character wildcards I was using in the sSubUnit string (from "2???" to "2%") and Voila'!  It works.  Thank you SO much for the article.