# Rs.update Issue in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to resolve an issue for writing the data into Access database using Excel VBA. Basically, our company has a spreadsheet that people can use to input data and save the data into Access database by clicking a button. Initially, the spreadsheet was working fine. However, after some time, several coworkers started to have issue saving the data. When they click the button, the cursor starts to turn and excel freezes/crashes (we had to force excel to close). This is very strange cause it happens randomly (my coworkers are just inputting some report data of different companies). Sometimes the data can be saved with no issue and sometimes the excel just crashes. Some coworker can input data from 5 companies but she can only successfully save 3 of them. So far, I have told them to save a copy of each company's data until this issue is resolved.

I have tried to debug and the problem seems to come from the rs.update syntax (the one shown below). Whenever VBA runs to this rs.update, it starts to crash. You can find this rs.update syntax from the actual coding I pasted below.

```
rs.Fields("TimeStamp") = load_time
                rs.Fields("User") = current_user_name
                rs.Fields("Ticker") = curr_ticker
                rs.Fields("LoadID") = this_entry_ID
                rs.Update
            Else
                ssss = 1
                 'rs.AddNew


Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("AIF_Summary", dbOpenTable)
     rs.AddNew
     rs.Fields("Ticker") = curr_ticker
     rs.Fields("Initiator") = current_user_name
     rs.Fields("StartDate") = Sheets("Main").Range("STARTDATE")
     rs.Fields("EffectiveDate") = Sheets("Main").Range("EFFECTIVEDATE")
     rs.Fields("EvaluationYear") = Sheets("Main").Range("EVALUATIONYEAR")
     rs.Fields("GLJ_Frac") = Sheets("Main").Range("GLJFRAC")
     rs.Fields("McDan_Frac") = Sheets("Main").Range("MCDANFRAC")
     rs.Fields("Sproule_Frac") = Sheets("Main").Range("SPROULEFRAC")
     rs.Fields("Other_Frac") = Sheets("Main").Range("OTHERFRAC")
     rs.Fields("CustomNotes") = Sheets("Main").Range("CUSTOMNOTES")
     rs.Fields("T1_CustomNotes") = Sheets("T1").Range("T1_CUSTOMNOTES")
     rs.Fields("T2_CustomNotes") = Sheets("T2").Range("T2_CUSTOMNOTES")
     rs.Fields("T3_CustomNotes") = Sheets("T3").Range("T3_CUSTOMNOTES")
     rs.Fields("T4_CustomNotes") = Sheets("T4").Range("T4_CUSTOMNOTES")
     rs.Fields("T5_CustomNotes") = Sheets("T5").Range("T5_CUSTOMNOTES")
     rs.Fields("T6_CustomNotes") = Sheets("T6").Range("T6_CUSTOMNOTES")
     rs.Fields("T7_CustomNotes") = Sheets("T7").Range("T7_CUSTOMNOTES")
     If Len(Sheets("Main").Range("OTHER_IQRE_NAME")) > 0 And Val(Sheets("Main").Range("OTHERFRAC")) > 0 Then
        rs.Fields("Other_IQRE_Name") = Sheets("Main").Range("OTHER_IQRE_NAME")
     End If
     rs.Fields("DataBaseFlag") = Sheets("Main").Range("DATABASEFLAG")
     rs.Fields("CompanyName") = Sheets("Main").Range("CompanyName")
     rs.Fields("AddedDateTime") = load_time
     rs.Fields("T1_Currency") = Sheets("T1").Range("T1_Currency")
     rs.Fields("T7_Currency") = Sheets("T7").Range("T7_Currency")
     rs.Fields("MIC_Currency") = Sheets("MIC").Range("MIC_Currency")
     rs.Fields("T1_PriceDeck") = Sheets("T1").Range("T1_PRICEDECK")
    
     this_entry_ID = rs.Fields("ID")
     rs.Update
     rs.Close
     
     
    Set rs = Nothing
     
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("AIF_Data", dbOpenTable)
   
    On Error GoTo -1
  
    For v = 1 To 1354
        
        var_value = ""
        If Mid(write_vars(v, 1), 1, 2) = "T1" Then var_value = Worksheets("T1").Range(write_vars(v, 1))
        If Mid(write_vars(v, 1), 1, 2) = "T2" Then var_value = Worksheets("T2").Range(write_vars(v, 1))
        If Mid(write_vars(v, 1), 1, 2) = "T3" Then var_value = Worksheets("T3").Range(write_vars(v, 1))
        If Mid(write_vars(v, 1), 1, 2) = "T4" Then var_value = Worksheets("T4").Range(write_vars(v, 1))
        If Mid(write_vars(v, 1), 1, 2) = "T5" Then var_value = Worksheets("T5").Range(write_vars(v, 1))
        If Mid(write_vars(v, 1), 1, 2) = "T6" Then var_value = Worksheets("T6").Range(write_vars(v, 1))
        If Mid(write_vars(v, 1), 1, 2) = "T7" Then var_value = Worksheets("T7").Range(write_vars(v, 1))
        
        If Len(var_value) > 0 Then
            rs.AddNew
            rs.Fields("VariableName") = write_vars(v, 1)
            
            If write_vars(v, 4) = "Liquid" Then
                rs.Fields("VariableValue") = var_value * liquid_unit_convert 'DB stores mbbl and mmcf as standard units
            End If
            
            If write_vars(v, 4) = "Gas" Then
                rs.Fields("VariableValue") = var_value * gas_unit_convert 'DB stores mbbl and mmcf as standard units
            End If
            
'            If write_vars(v, 4) = "T1_Currency" Then
'                rs.Fields("VariableValue") = var_value * currency_unit_convert 'DB stores $ as standard units
'            End If
'
'            If write_vars(v, 4) <> "Liquid" And write_vars(v, 4) <> "Gas" And write_vars(v, 4) <> "T1_Currency" Then
'                rs.Fields("VariableValue") = var_value
'            End If
            
            If write_vars(v, 4) <> "Liquid" And write_vars(v, 4) <> "Gas" And write_vars(v, 4) <> "T1_Currency" Then
                rs.Fields("VariableValue") = var_value
            End If
                
            If write_vars(v, 4) = "T1_Currency" Then
                rs.Fields("VariableValue").Value = var_value * currency_unit_convert 'DB stores $ as standard units
            End If
            
            rs.Fields("TimeStamp") = load_time
            rs.Fields("User") = current_user_name
            rs.Fields("Ticker") = curr_ticker
            rs.Fields("LoadID") = this_entry_ID
            rs.Update
        Else
            ssss = 1
             'rs.AddNew
            'rs.Fields("VariableName") = write_vars(v, 1)
            'rs.Fields("VariableValue") = 0
            'rs.Fields("TimeStamp") = load_time
            'rs.Fields("User") = current_user_name
            'rs.Fields("Ticker") = curr_ticker
            'rs.Fields("LoadID") = this_entry_ID
            'rs.Update
        
        End If
    
    Next v
    ADOFromExcelToAccess this_entry_ID

    Sheets("Database Variables").Visible = False
    Sheets("Companies").Visible = False
End Sub
```

Can someone share his opinion?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some details to your question that could be relevant to this problem. Does it crash updating `AIF_Summary` or `AIF_Data` table ? How many records does each table hold ?  Are several users entering data at the same time ? Is the database on a network drive and if so is the spreadsheet on the same drive ? Do the tables have any long text/memo fields ? What it the version of Access and which on which operating system ? What is write_vars() ? I assume it is the values of a range on the spreadsheet. My opinion would be use SQL insert statements rather that record set updates.

Comment: @CDP1802 Hi there, thank you very much for your feedback. 1. It crashes when updating AIF_Data table. 2. AIF_Summary table has less than 5000 records. Every time when users save the data in database through spreadsheet, it creates an ID for a specific company and a specific year.  AIF_Data table now holds 700K rows of data. As I know, Access should be enough to hold this much data. 3. Yes, several users entering the data at the same time.  4. The database and spreadsheet are in the same drive. 5. AIF_Summary table use short text for some columns. 6.  Access version is (16.0.13801.20288) 64 bit

Comment: write_vars = Sheets("Database Variables").Range("A2:D1355")    so you are right, it is a range of values.. What is the benefit of using SQL insert instead of Rs. update?

Comment: How are you declaring and setting the db object. I guess you are using Data Access Object (DAO) rather than Active X Data Objects (ADO) see [difference-between-ado-and-dao](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737099/difference-between-ado-and-dao) and [converting-dao-code-to-ado](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/converting-dao-code-to-ado)