# executing SQL in workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am unable to execute a simple sql statement. - sorry I am sure this is simple and I am missing something small. Error says missing the object.

```
dbPath = "C:\Users\User\Documents\test0419.accdb"
tblName = "Wait_Data_Table"
strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & dbPath & "';"

conn.Open strcon

Set wrkSpaceNew = DBEngine.CreateWorkspace("Check", "admin", "", dbUseJet)

rcdDetail = ("SELECT order.ord_id, order.job_id, order.bc_desc, order.ord_amount, order.ord_diff FROM Order")

Set rs = DBEngine.BeginTrans(rcdDetail)
```

Comment: `BeginTrans` is to start a transaction. `OpenRecordset` is what you need.

Comment: What have you declared variable conn as ?

Comment: My goal is to run a simple sql querry on a local dB.  Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection, rs As New ADODB.Recordset, dbPath As String
Dim  rcdDetail As String
Dim  strcon As String,
Dim rs2 As Recordset
Dim wrkSpaceNew As Workspace
Dim obj1 As Object
Dim obj2 As Object
Dim db As DAO.Database
dbPath = "C:\Users\User\Documents\test0419.accdb"
strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & dbPath & "';"

conn.Open strcon
Set wrkSpaceNew = DBEngine.CreateWorkspace("Check", "admin", "", dbUseJet)

rcdDetail = ("SELECT order.ord_id, order.ord_diff FROM Order")

Set rc2 =

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `DAO` or `ADODB`, not normally both. See [difference-between-ado-and-dao](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737099/difference-between-ado-and-dao)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UseDAO()
  
   Const SQL = " SELECT order.ord_id, order.job_id, order.bc_desc, " & _
               "        order.ord_amount, order.ord_diff " & _
               " FROM [Order]"
     
   Const dbpath = "C:\Users\User\Documents\test0419.accdb"
  
   Dim wkspace As workspace, db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
   Set wkspace = DBEngine.CreateWorkspace("Check", "admin", "", dbUseJet)
   Set db = wkspace.OpenDatabase(dbpath)
   
   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)
   Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
   db.Close
   Set db = Nothing
   wkspace.Close
   Set wkspace = Nothing
  
   MsgBox "Results on sheet " & Sheet1.Name, vbInformation, "DAO"

End Sub

Sub UseADODB()
  
   Const SQL = " SELECT order.ord_id, order.job_id, order.bc_desc, " & _
               "        order.ord_amount, order.ord_diff " & _
               " FROM [Order]"
     
   Const dbpath = "C:\Users\User\Documents\test0419.accdb"
  
   Dim strConn As String, conn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
   strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & dbpath & "';"
   Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
   conn.Open strConn

   Set rs = conn.Execute(SQL)
   Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
   conn.Close
   
   MsgBox "Results on sheet " & Sheet1.Name, vbInformation, "ADODB"

End Sub
```

Comment: What would cause a run time error 424 missing object? We get past the connection It hangs at the  Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordser rs.  I stepped through a couple times watching and it was fine.

Comment: i was using the ADODB connections

Comment: When commented out it errors out at then msgBox  - object required

Comment: @Dave I'm guessing you don't have Option Explicit at the start of your code and you have deleted Sheet1. Use another sheet.

Comment: I was under the understanding that Option Explicit assists when defining variable but how did that effect the object?

Comment: @Dave With Option Explicit you should get a compiler error "Variable not defined" if Sheet1 did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add Activex Data Object in Reference Section

```
Dim baglanti As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sunucu, veritabani, id, sifre, sorgu As String

sunucu = "DESKTOP-GF32DLC\SQLEXPRESS"
veritabani = "AdventureWorks2014"
id = ""
sifre = ""
sorgu = "SELECT * FROM [HumanResources].[Department] Where [GroupName]='Manufacturing'"

baglanti.Open "Driver={SQL SERVER};Server=" & sunucu & ";Database=" & veritabani & _
";Uid=" & id & ";Pwd=" & sifre & ";"

rs.Open sorgu, baglanti, adOpenStatic

With Range("A1:AA1000")
.ClearContents
.CopyFromRecordset rs
End With

rs.Close
baglanti.Close
```

This way you can make a healthy sql connection.
I used to use it to connect sql in the past