# Open a Table in a Form using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

In the "old" days, in order for me to search a "Table" for specific data in a vba statement in a "Form"/"Event"  in MS Access 2003, that I chose.  I would use the following code:

---

```
Set Table_ID = New ADODB.Recordset

Table_ID.CursorLocation = adUseClient

Table_ID.Open "Select * From Table_ID", _

  CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

---

The above code gives me the following message when I ran it MS Access 2019:

> Microsoft Visual Basic for Application    Compile error: User-defined type not defined

I changed the "ADODB" with the database I'm using in MS Access 2019 as follows:

```
Set Table_ID = New DB002.Recordset
```

When I ran it again in MS Access 2019, the same message appeared.

Please advise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737099/difference-between-ado-and-dao

Comment: For ADODB, probably need to activate Microsoft ActiveX Data x.x Objects Library reference from the VBA editor Tools > References. I have never seen DB002.

Comment: What are you doing with this recordset? Maybe instead of opening recordset, just use DLookup() domain aggregate function.